# Acces second child of dynamically generated button

Tags: javascript, css

For a personal project I am generating a list of buttons based off of data of an array of objects. The buttons contain two parts: the button text and a detailed paragraph below the button text. My functions already succesfully generate the div, button and paragraph without issue.

At the moment, the paragraph's display style defaults on hidden. I want it to be turned in to a block display.

I am accessing the button with the following code:

```
function updateClicks() {
    var coll = document.querySelectorAll(".generatedDiv");
    var i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
            coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                var content = this.getElementsByTagName("p");
                if (content[0].firstChild.style.display === "block") {
                    content.style.display = "none";
                } else {
                    content.style.display = "block";
                }
            });
        }
}
```

The structure of the div is as follows:

```
<button class="generatedDiv">
    <table>
        <td>Button text #1</td>
        <td>Button text #2</td>
    </table>
    <p>
        Additional Information
    </p>
</button>
```

I can acces the typed "Additional Information" via these functions, however I cannot edit the style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue here is, you're counting on `this` to remain the same, and it's not. I tutor often on both FreeCodeCamp and The Odin Project, and it's a common dilemma. You can't really rely on `this` to be what you think it should be. Once you're in an inner function (like the click handler function), then the context has changed, and thus your `this` isn't the same.

Instead, consider another option. What you're doing here is handling an event, right? But your function isn't an event handler, in that it doesn't expect an `Event` object. If you rewrite your function a little, then things start to move a little more like you expect:

```js
function updateClicks() {
  var coll = document.querySelectorAll(".generatedDiv");
  var i = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      var content = event.target.closest(".generatedDiv").querySelector("p");
      if (content.style.display !== "none") {
        content.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        content.style.display = "block";
      }
    });
  }
}


updateClicks()
```

```html
<div class="generatedDiv">
  <h2>The first toggler</h2>
  <table>
    <td><button>Any click...</button></td>
    <td><button>...will toggle the p</button></td>
  </table>
<p>Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
<div class="generatedDiv">
  <h2>The second toggler</h2>
  <table>
    <td><button>but only...</button></td>
    <td><button>the p that is within this div</button></td>
  </table>


<p>Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I very much appreciate the added insight on ```this```!

Comment: Glad to help. It's a very common thing, `this` changes dynamically. If you haven't yet, I recommend reading https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS section on scope and closures.